# Crashes with some types sfml on android

Tags: android, c++, compiler-errors, sfml

Programmed on android, and more specifically in ***cxxdroid*** and ***c4droid***. In both programs, I caught crashes when creating variables of the types `sf::Texture`  and `sf::RenderWindow` not into main(), but visual studio don't have problems with it

basic example:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
using namespace sf;
RenderWindow window(VideoMode(1080, 1920), "sfml"); //crashing

int main()
{
while (window.isOpen())
    {
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

window.clear();
window.display();
    }
return 0;
}
```

Can you tell me how to create its variables before main() or advise another compiler for android that has no problems with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `RenderWindow` and `Texture`, I guessed to use references **&type_name** in variables for the function.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
using namespace sf;

Sprite sprite;

void WinUse(RenderWindow &window)
{
    window.draw(sprite);
}

int main()
{
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(1080, 1920), "sfml");
    
    
    Texture texture;
    texture.loadFromFile("any.png");
    sprite.setTexture(texture);
    
    
while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

window.clear();
WinUse(window);
window.display();
    }
return 0;
}
```